# Simplify casts to type which depends on a parameter

Tags: c++, templates, casting

I have data in a void pointer that need to be cast in a type depending on an Integer received in parameter.

First thought would be doing a simple if/switch statement like:

```
if (dataType == 1)
  data = dynamic_cast<char *>(void_pointer);
else if (dataType == 2)
  data = dynamic_cast<int *>(void_pointer);
...
```

This works but it can get quite long if you have dozens of type to cast into.
I would like to know if the ifs statements can be simplified, for example, using templates ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The snippet makes not much sense. The return type can only be either `char*` or `int*` but not both

Comment: FWIW, your use of `dynamic_cast` is illegal.  `dynamic_cast` is meant for polymorphic casts.

Comment: First, `dynamic_cast` is meant to be used with polymorphic types. Second, what is the return type of your function? If this compiles, its likely that the cast doesn't matter because the returned value will certainly be cast down to the common type anyway.

Comment: "I have data in a void pointer" Dont ! It is rarely ever needed to use `void*` in C++.

Comment: your edit didnt make the snippet much better. If you can assign any type of pointer to `data`, then why do you need the cast in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `decltype`:

```
data = static_cast<decltype(int_parameter) *>(void_pointer);
```

and not `dynamic_cast` (which is for polymorphic types) but `static_cast` is used for this type of casting.

Comment: Would be nice to explain why `static_cast` instead of `dynamic_cast` given how the OP has no idea when and where to use `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Now I really want to know what the type of `data` is if you can assign a `char*` or a `int*` to it.

Comment: @NathanOliver Good point, was wondering that myself. Maybe the code is a snippet of a templated function?

Comment: @PaulEvans The `if` is not `constexpr` so the return type has to be the same for each branch. Either its `void*` and the casts don't do anything or its some sort of variant type. If its a variant, you have to wonder why this function exists in the first place instead of using the variant type directly. Maybe its to translate from some preexisting system to a more sane variant-based system.